# CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged gives me before AND after changes to a cell. Why?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am attempting to catch changes made in a datagridview by using the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event.  When a user makes a change to a cell in the datagridview, I'm capturing the 'before' image and saving it to a `List`.  The problem is that, somehow, my code is adding both the before and after image to my list, so I end up with two entries.  When I step through with debug, it appears the program is executing the last three statements of my method twice. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a list to hold before changes.
        changeList = new List<ChangeLogObject>();

        var beforeChange = new ChangeLogObject
        {
            UserName = Environment.UserName,
            TimeChanged = DateTime.Now,
            State = "Before",
            Mode = "Lesson",
            Hive = this.ddlHive.Text,
            Project = this.ddlProjects.Text,
            Mission = this.ddlMissions.Text,
            Module = this.ddlModules.Text,
            Course = this.ddlCourses.Text,
            Frame = (int)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value,
            LayerTitle = (string)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value,
            LayerText = (string)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value,
            GraphicNumber = (string)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value,
            Height = (int)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value,
            Width = (int)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value,
            X = (int)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value,
            Y = (int)this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value
        };

        this.dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
        this.changeList.Add(beforeChange);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your eventhandling method only examine whether the cell is dirty, if so fire the CommitEdit (=Cellvaluechanged ev. handling method)
link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx